# Do "multiple choice" questions always have only one correct answer?

Tags: word-usage, ambiguity, variants, dialects

In most dictionary definitions it seems that "multiple choice" questions actually refer to questions where only one "correct" answer among several choices is expected to be chosen (e.g. the definition from [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/multiple-choice) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice) (Not such a good source, I know). However, some other sources online purport that "one or more answer choices" can also be allowed under "multiple choice" questions (e.g. the [description of the GRE exam](https://www.ets.org/gre/revised_general/prepare/quantitative_reasoning/multiple_choice_more/)).

What would be the correct interpretation of "multiple choice" here? Is there any regional variation at play? If it mostly refers to questions with exactly one correct answer, how should the questioner avoid misunderstanding if the question explicitly expects more than one answers to be chosen?

Comment: Many multiple-choice questions have multiple correct answers - they tend to use phrases such as 'tick all that apply'…

If you're asking how to compose multiple-choice questionnaires the basic choices are specialized training courses or long experience.

Comment: I've seen many tests before where it says "pick the *most correct* answer". I know that bugs a few people because you can't exactly have a "degree" of correctness.

Comment: Certainly you see multiple-choice queries with options of "all of the above" and "none of the above".

Comment: In the context of web-based forms (which comes, iirc, from the Apple Macintosh UI, which, of course, was based on the work done at Xerox Parc for the Alto), there are _checkboxes_ and _radio buttons_.  The latter allows only one choice (the name comes from the preset buttons on a radio) while the former allows the user to check (or tick, depending on which side of the pond you're on) all that apply.  In the context of a test, I imagine it's up to the teacher to decide how many correct answers will be provided.

Comment: @HotLicks Then the implication is that there is only one correct answer among the multiple choices. The answerer is not free to choose a combination of different choices.

Comment: @RogerSinasohn Yeah I also thought "checkbox" would definitely be correct, especially to people with UI/frontend experience. However, if I put in a questionnaire targeted at the general public "checkbox questions", it just sounds weird in some way.

Comment: There should be clear directions and they should be bolded if deviating from the convention of picking "the best" answer.  Many polls and surveys use "click all that apply" directions and, with proper warning, you could instrument a test that way.

Comment: @JIXiang - There is no hard-and-fast rule here.

Comment: Can you give us the context where you'd like to use the phrase? *Multiple choice question* is occasionally used as an idiom, where it might have a specific interpretation based on context. On an actual test or survey, I would expect more exact directions to make it unambiguous.